# LINQ - array property contains element from another array

Tags: .net, linq, arrays, filter

I have a object (product), with a property of type 'array'
e.g. product.tags = {"tag1","tag2","tag9"}

I have an array of input tags to filter on.

... but this is not quite working:

```
List<string> filterTags = new List<string>() { "tag1", "tag3" };

var matches = from p in products
  where p.Tags.Contains(filterTags)
  select p;
```

Any recommendations?
Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

What is the `Contains` really meant to achieve? Do all items in `Tags` need to exist in `filterTags`? Or at least one of them? For the latter use `Any` and for the former use `All`. Your `where` line would change to:

```
where p.Tags.Any(tag => filterTags.Contains(tag))
```

or

```
where p.Tags.All(tag => filterTags.Contains(tag))
```

Comment: Thanks ... great. It meant 'any' actually. ....   
"... show all products that contain one-or-more of the input tags". I'll give that a go. THANK-YOU!

Comment: As LINQ for anyone interested: `context.Products.Where(p => p.Tags.Any(tag => filterTags.Contains(tag)))`

Comment: @Mike _As LINQ_? Isn't what's given in the answer LINQ? Of course it is. What you've shown is called extension method syntax BTW.

Answer (score -1):

```
var small = new List<int> { 1, 2 };
var big = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

bool smallIsInBig = small.All(x => big.Contains(x));
// true

bool bigIsInSmall = big.All(x => small.Contains(x));
// false

bool anyBigIsInSmall = big.Any(x => small.Contains(x));
// true
```