# How to check if a name is contained in another collection

Tags: c#, linq

I am doing something like this currently:

```
allSales.Where(x => x.location == "NorthAmerica" && x.CompanyName);
```

I have a `List<Company>` and the Company object has a .CompanyName property.

I want to filter for sales that have a CompanyName that are in the List collection.

The Company class has the following properties:

```
Company
Id
Name
```

The below doesn't work but it is what I want:

```
allSales.Where(x => x.location == "NorthAmerica" && 
       companies.Exists(x => x.Name = x.CompanyName));
```

where companies is List

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ - array property contains element from another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539442/linq-array-property-contains-element-from-another-array)

Comment: use the `.Contains` function

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @MethodMan Doesn't contains look for the entire method?  I just want to compare Company.Name and x.CompanyName

Comment: Try this: `&& companies.Any(c => c.Name == x.CompanyName)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a `List<Company>` in a variable `companies`, you can use LINQ [`Any` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534972(v=vs.100).aspx) to do something like this:

```
allSales
.Where(x =>
    x.location == "NorthAmerica" &&
    companies.Any(c => c.Name == x.CompanyName));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Any()` method on your `List<Company>` object with a query to return true or false to your predicate. Try something like:

```
allSales.Where(x => x.location == "NorthAmerica" && companies.Any(c => c.Name == x.CompanyName);
```